# What is the quotient $q$ of the geometric sum?

Tags: calculus

The progression $a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ is geometric. If $a_1+a_3+a_5=455,$ and $a_2+a_4+a_6=1365$, what is the quotient $q$ of the progression?

This means that $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=\sum_{n=1}^{6}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{6}q^n=\frac{q^{7}-q}{q-1}=455+1365=1820.$$

I can't solve this equation of 7th degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $a_{n+1} = qa_{n}$ we have
$$
a_2 + a_4 + a_6 = q(a_1 + a_3 + a_5),
$$
or $1365 = q\cdot 465$. So $q = 3$.

Comment: How do you know that $a_{n+1}=a_nq$?

Comment: @Parseval as $\{a_n\}$ is a geometric progression

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases} a_{ 1 }+a_{ 3 }+a_{ 5 }=455 \\ a_{ 2 }+a_{ 4 }+a_{ 6 }=1365 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} { a }_{ 1 }+{ a }_{ 1 }{ q }^{ 2 }+{ a }_{ 1 }{ q }^{ 4 }=455 \\ { a }_{ 1 }q+{ a }_{ 1 }{ q }^{ 3 }+{ a }_{ 1 }{ q }^{ 5 }=1355 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} { a }_{ 1 }\left( 1+{ q }^{ 2 }+{ q }^{ 4 } \right) =455 \\ { a }_{ 1 }q\left( 1+{ q }^{ 2 }+{ q }^{ 4 } \right) =1355 \end{cases}\\ \frac { 1 }{ q } =\frac { 455 }{ 1355 } \Rightarrow q=3$$

Comment: How come $a_3=a_1q^2$?

Comment: it comes from the definition of $nth$ term's formula ${ a }_{ n }={ a }_{ 1 }{ q }^{ n-1 }$

Comment: According to the answer above it's $a_n=qa_{n-1}$. This is confusing.

Comment: @Parseval, $${ a }_{ 2 }=q{ a }_{ 1 }\\ { a }_{ 3 }=q{ a }_{ 2 }={ q }^{ 2 }a_{ 1 }\\ { a }_{ 4 }=q{ a }_{ 3 }=q\underset { { a }_{ 3 } }{ \underbrace { { q }^{ 2 }a_{ 1 } }  } ={ q }^{ 3 }{ a }_{ 1 }\\ ......\\ { a }_{ n }={ { q }^{ n-1 }a }_{ 1 }$$